# RMarkdown dynamic hyperlinks

Tags: r, dynamic, hyperlink, r-markdown

I have been lately busy writing an RMarkdown document that would render a pdf report with information about genetic variants. However, the readers for whom the reports are intended asked whether I could embed a link to the UCSC Genome Browser to view the variant in context. I'm actually looping through the variants in a table and printing the annotations thus:

```
for i in nrows(table){cat("Region:"}
```

I know that if I do this:

```
for i in nrows(table){cat("[Region:](www.somewebsite.com)")}
```

I can get the word "Region" to become a clickable hyperlink in the final PDF. My problem is that the link should be dynamic (i.e. the link should take the genomic coordinates for that particular variant). I've been looking for hours but can't find a way to do that. Is that possible in R/RMarkdown or should I change my strategy?

Thanks!

Comment: You’d do it in RMarkdown the same as you’d do it with any other link. How would you generate a USCS link for a given gene? Just plop that into your `for` loop …

Comment: Yes, I can do that using the paste function (e.g. paste("http://www.ucscwebsite",position, sep="")), but I was wondering whether I can use the word "Region" as a hyperlink to avoid having to print out the very long link to the genomic position in UCSC Genome Browser. For now, that doesn't work as anything in parenthesis is taken literally.

Comment: No, nothing about the parentheses is special. But you cannot have R code inside the string, obviously.